# How to implement argparse in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-arguments, argparse

I'm new to Python, I got a small script to upload files to S3, at the moment I only hard-code one single file in the script, the bucket name is also hard-coded.

I wanted to merge argparse in this script so that I can add some arguements by myself and upload different files. For example, in the command line I can specify arguments to decide `file_name x` upload to `bucket_name xxx`.

I've been reading documents about how to set argparse but I can only make small changes and don't know how to implement it with the function in my script (I guess `os.rename` will be unnecessary because we'll parse the arguements by ourselves). I know the logic, just having difficulty to implement them in the actual code... Can someone gave me an example or gave me some hint, many thanks.

Comment: if you specify the timestamp name to upload, what is the point of having that logic in your script?

Comment: Because I have many different files (generated from a model, without timestamp), I want to add a timestamp before uploading them

Comment: yes but the logic to _derive_ a timestamp happens in your script so how would you pass it as an argument? the current filename and bucket make sense as inputs but the third one does not. are you saying you will be providing the full renamed test file with timestamp as an input?

Comment: Ah I get you, I guess it's not appropriate to parse that as a parameter, I just want the script to handle it and upload it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: so then the script would only take two inputs, correct? if that's the case please revise the question.

Comment: I've updated the question, thanks. Sorry for the confusion, I guess it would take two parameters (unless there is a better approach).

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how the script would look taking command line arguments.

```
import argparse
import datetime
import logging
import os
import boto3


def make_new_key(filename: str):
    current_date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H_%M_%S')
    # The next line handles the case where you are passing the
    # full path to the file as opposed to just the name
    name = os.path.basename(filename)

    parts = name.split('.')
    new_name = f"{parts[0]}{current_date}.csv"
    return new_name

def upload_to_s3(source_filename: str, new_name: str, bucket: str):
    logging.info(f"Uploading to S3 from {source_filename} to {bucket} {key}")
    s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
    with open(source_filename, 'rb') as file:
        response = s3_client.put_object(Body=file,
                                        Bucket=bucket,
                                        Key=new_name,
                                        ACL="bucket-owner-full-control")
        logging.info(response)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--filename')
    parser.add_argument('--bucket')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    new_name = make_new_key(args.filename)
    upload_to_s3(args.filename, new_name, args.bucket)
```

Then you would call the script like this

```
python upload.py --filename path/to/file --bucket name_of_bucket
```

Comment: Hi just wondering is there an example of the unit test of codes with 'argparse', I'm still learning how to write the unit test, would be great if you could give me some hints.

Comment: you wouldn’t be testing argparse. you would just be testing your functions and providing input to them as necessary so the fact that argparse is used here is not relevant

Comment: How can I test the first function when it's deriving the current datetime?

Comment: provide a string that looks like a path on a computer. seems straightforward.

Comment: The main issue is the current datetime, here's what I've tried ```    def test_make_new_key(self):
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.strftime('2020-04-12_12_02_30') expected_result = upload.make_new_key('test.csv')
        self.assertEqual(expected_result, 'test_2020-04-12_12_02_30_raw.csv')
``` it gave me error ```TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'str'```

Comment: why are you providing a string to that datetime function? you use `strftime` on a datetime object which is not what you are doing. with that being said I am not going to answer any more questions on this post which are out of context. if you are having additional issues ask a new question.